Can we use SQL FREETEXTTABLE to compare values in 2 table columns instead of an explicit input value?
To be specific, I need to find 'duplicate' records where new customer accounts may have been created with similar names. For example  "Smith's stores"  and "Smith Store' could be such duplicates. So I need to perform a free text similar match on other records in the same table rather than sending an input value.
This is how I do it with a value, but if I try to use a column name from table a, I get an error.
SELECT key_tbl.[rank],  * FROM Accounts a
JOIN FREETEXTTABLE (Accounts, AccountName, 'Smith store')  as key_tbl
on key_tbl.[key] = a.DW_id
ORDER BY key_tbl.[RANK] DESC


The FREETEXTTABLE function in SQL Server is designed to work with an explicit input value for searching. Unfortunately, it doesn't support using column values directly as input for searching.

You can use a variable though, so you could concat all your search conditions as or using STRING_AGG, and pass to CONTAINSTABLE instead. Or put it into a multi-statement (not inline) Table Valued Function so you can CROSS APPLY it but not it will be slow.
